# How to store Realm Sync client data encrypted on MongoDB Atlas (enable Zero-Knowledge encryption)?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, encryption, realm

Currently data can be encrypted on the Realm client device, but is stored unencrypted in MongoDB Atlas as the quote below shows. I want data to be encrypted with a Zero-Knowledge encryption approach:

"Zero-Knowledge encryption means that service providers know nothing about the content of the data you store on their servers." Field names can be unencrypted, but the actual data should be encrypted (*'field encryption'*).  For example the [Joplin App](https://joplinapp.org/e2ee/) is taking such an approach, calling it [End to End Encryption.](https://joplinapp.org/e2ee/#about-end-to-end-encryption-e2ee)

Therefore the private key should be generated on the device and not be stored on the server and should only be accessible to the user.

I believe this is not built-in with the current version of *Realm Sync / MongoDB Atlas*. For my use case, the data on the device still needs to be accessible for a search query (unencrypted while logged in), but I do not need to be able to search the data on the Atlas Server, as searching the local data is sufficient.

I wonder, if Realm (on the device) provides any hooks which makes this possible. Would encryption possibly get in the way synchronisation? What would be a feasible approach I could use to encrypt the data with a private key, before it is sent to the server and synchronised?

**References:**

> #### Documentation: [Encryption and Realm Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/advanced/encrypt/#encryption-and-realm-sync)
>
> You can encrypt a [synced realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/sync-changes-between-devices/#std-label-react-native-open-a-synced-realm). MongoDB Realm only encrypts the data on the device and stores the data unencrypted in your MongoDB Atlas [data source](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/get-started/glossary/#std-term-data-source).

- MongoDB does provide [Field Level Encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/) (for their Enterprise version), but this does not appear to be available via the Realm mobile SDKs. *(Also, my project does not have access to the enterprise version.)*

Comment: I am pretty sure that's not an option. You're looking to have local data encrypted but also the data that's sync'd and stored on the server and unfortunately that's not how Realm works. While the data is secure and encrypted in transit, it's stored as clear text in Atlas - otherwise there wouldn't be a way to run queries against it. I don't think you can intercept that process. Thinking outside the box; Realm is an offline first database so perhaps you could have two Realms - one non-synch'd but Realm encrypted and a Realm where, via software, all data is encrypted that sync's.

Comment: Your idea of using two local databases is interesting. I will look more into it. I would have to locally sync data between the two databases and use an encryption scheme where the same plaintext will always result in the same cipher text to prevent unnecessary syncing. - Synching with these encrypted fields should still work, as every encrypted field would basically be a string. - I think I will try a simple proof-of-concept based on this idea.

Comment: Hi @ChrisW, have you tried the suggested idea? I have a project planning to use realm for data sync and the data included personal data and health data. Can you please share you findings?